# Plotting numpy array like qutip quantum object

Tags: matrix, plot, qutip

I like the way that qutip plots quantum objects and I would like to plot my regular arrays like this. Does someone know if they are using any particular library or how to replicate it?

Here is an image of what I mean:
[I want to plot the objects like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75rqo.png)

It can be found in this notebook:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jrjohansson/qutip-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-0-Introduction-to-QuTiP.ipynb

Thank you :D